# MongoDB tree structure with more than 16MB

Tags: mongodb, tree, database, nosql

Im working on a project that we have a deep hierarchy to store:

- **Areas** (5 items)

  - **Subjects** (~6 items for each area)

    - **Competences** ( ~10 items for each capacity)

      - **Capacities** ( ~20 items for each subject)

        - **Acknowledgement** ( 20 items for each competence)

          - **Question** (15 items for each Acknowledgement)

So with this we're having more than 16MB per document so we cant build in a single document.

We're thinking about to split each level into a single collection but sounds weird because its too similar to the relation model.

Actually we're splitting the areas in separated document but its exploding the limit anyway.

What should be a good approach to this case?

We can't use a relational model because we have inconsistent data and definition of a schema can disrupt.

Thanks for the help =)